# Вопрос по установке MySql

Tags: mysql

При установке сервера MySql сначала требовал установить Visual Studio. Visual Studio требовала установить NET Framework. Я установил NET Framework 4.7 и Android Xtudio 2017 года. Теперь при попытке установить сервер MySql выдается ошибка

> This application requires Visual Studio 2013 Redistributable. Please install the Redistributable then run this installer again.

Как победить эту беду?

Comment: использую Windows 8.1 64-разрядную

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно установить Visual C++ Redistributable 2013
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Comment: устанавливал, все равно та же ошибка появляется